# How to ensure my Ajax call is finished before calling a new function inside window.onload?

Tags: javascript, ajax

**I do not use Json or jquery at this point - plain vanilla Javascript answers only please** (I've found a bunch of answers to this problem on SE, but they all include Jquery or Json).

I have two functions inside a `window.onload=function(){...` event handler.  The first function `fillArray(from,to)` is an Ajax call of the form:

```
function fillArray(from,to){
  request = createRequest();
  if (request == null) {
    return;
  }
  var url= "Ajax_retrieveNames.php?indexFrom=" + from + "&indexTo=" + to;
  request.open("GET", url, true);
  request.onreadystatechange = populateArray;
  request.send(null);
}

function populateArray(){
  var xmlFrag=null;
  if (request.readyState == 4) {
    if (request.status == 200) {
      xmlFrag = request.responseXML;
      for(var i=indexFrom; i<=indexTo; i++){
        fcArray[i]=new Array();
        var f=xmlFrag.getElementsByTagName("first")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        var l=xmlFrag.getElementsByTagName("last")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        fcArray[i][0]=f;
        fcArray[i][1]=l;
      }
    }else{
      return;
    }
  }else{
    return;
  }
}
```

The second function `showNextName()` deals with formatting and displaying the elements of the next (in this case first) sub-array.  At this point, the `var arrayIndex` is set to 0:

```
function showNextName(){
  displayQuestion() // Deals with page formatting
  document.getElementById('firstName').innerHTML=fcArray[arrayIndex][0];
  document.getElementById('lastName').innerHTML=fcArray[arrayIndex][1];
  updateArrayIndex(); // Is a counter that increments the variable arrayIndex
}
```

My problem is that the script goes into the second function, `showNextName()`, before completing the Ajax call and populating the array.  I can recolve that by incorporating a timer between the two functions but that's clumsy.  Is there a better way to make sure we do not get into `showNextName()` or leave `window.onload` until the Ajax call is completed and the array is populated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `showNextName` in your success callback (`populateArray`).  Since AJAX is asynchronous, you need to exectute logic depending on it when the `readyState` is 4 like you did in the `populateArray` function.

```
function populateArray(){
  var xmlFrag=null;
  if (request.readyState == 4) {
    if (request.status == 200) {
      xmlFrag = request.responseXML;
      for(var i=indexFrom; i<=indexTo; i++){
        fcArray[i]=new Array();
        var f=xmlFrag.getElementsByTagName("first")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        var l=xmlFrag.getElementsByTagName("last")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        fcArray[i][0]=f;
        fcArray[i][1]=l;
      }
      showNextName();
    }else{
      return;
    }
  }else{
    return;
  }
}
```

Comment: That works but I use `populateArray` in other cases where I don't want to call `showNextName()`.  I suppose I could use a variable as a flag and only call `showNextName()` if the flag is "up"...

Comment: @JDelage or you could decouple `populateArray` from your `readyState` check and only call it when you need to.

Answer (score 1):

The only sensible solution is to call `showNextName` from inside `populateArray`, once the latter has done its work.

Comment: That works but I use `populateArray` in other cases where I don't want to call `showNextName()`.  I suppose I could use a variable as a flag and only call `showNextName()` if the flag is "up"...